# conda install error: PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current linux-64 channels:

Tags: anaconda

I have been trying to use conda install pydicom, which has the following error message. How to solve this problem, thanks.

```
conda install conda-forge pydicom
Fetching package metadata .........

PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current linux-64 channels:
```

- conda-forge

```
Close matches found; did you mean one of these?

   conda-forge: conda-env
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `-c` to specify the channel.

```
conda install -c conda-forge pydicom
```